# python Get cumulative sum until condition is met in another column, then reset

Tags: python, python-3.x, cumulative-sum

I have 3 columns. I want to get the cumulative return given there is no trade. Once there is a trade, then reset the starting point of the cumulative return.

| Return | Price | Trade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.00 | 400 | 0 |
| 0.08 | 432.00 | 0 |
| 0.04 | 419.28 | -30 |
| 0.02 | 427.6656 | 0 |
| 0.06 | 513.325536 | 60 |
| 0.10 | 564.65809 | 0 |

I am trying to do a cumulative return by each row using `iterrows()`, but no luck. Would somebody know how to get this output?

Comment: (1) Show what you tried as properly formatted code in the question. (2) If the question is related to pandas add the appropriate tag.

Comment: post the expected result

Answer (score 0):

`Trade` values can be divided into groups using condition `~df.Trade.eq(0)` (`Trade` not equal to `0`) as a split point; to further calculate cumulative sums:

```
df['Ret_cumsum'] = df.groupby((~df.Trade.eq(0)).cumsum())['Return'].cumsum()
```

---

```
   Return       Price  Trade  Ret_cumsum
0    0.00  400.000000      0        0.00
1    0.08  432.000000      0        0.08
2    0.04  419.280000    -30        0.04
3    0.02  427.665600      0        0.06
4    0.06  513.325536     60        0.06
5    0.10  564.658090      0        0.16
```